# How to animate along any axis according to this picture?

Tags: animation, axis

I want to animate flipping book to both sides without separate planes. So how do I animate this plane according to the picture? Sorry about my grammar problems. I just trying to tell my problem. I think you guys can understand.

Thank you very much ☺️[image: image description here]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a loop cut to your plane like this:

[image]

Add an armature like this:

[image]

in object mode, select the plane, shift-select the armature, ctrl-P -> with empty groups

[image]

in face select mode, select that face, select the first bone group and press assign.
Do the same with the other face and the second bone group.

now select the armature in object mode, go to pose mode, select the bone:

[image]

move your timeline to frame 1
press I to insert keyframe

move your timeline to frame 20

press R X and rotate the bone as much as you like, hit I

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. I really appreciate your work. It's really helpful.

Comment: you are welcome